# Firebase Database onValue returning Observable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Before Firebase v9 I used `.snapshotChanges()` to return an Observable with the sapshot data. So I used this in my GUI-Layer to handle the data.

The new API does not provide returning Observables. Instead I have to use Callbacks to handle the data.

```
const ref = ref(db, 'path');
onValue(ref, (snapshot) => {
  //handle data
});
```

That mixes Code between database logic (own service) and other layers (i.e. component/gui).

Is there a way to return an Observable (like it was possible with the old API)? Or what is the best way to handle data outside my database service?